# Error: Program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser

Tags: android, dependencies, android-multidex, xmlpullparser

I'm getting this error when building a project, it seems that I have 2 libraries in my Gradle that are using the XML parser I tried to exclude it but it's not working.

Error: Program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser

Can anyone help me please in the right syntax for excluding the library?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId ''
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 4
    versionName '4.0.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

  def lastestMaterialDrawerRelease = '6.0.9'
    dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation files('libs/magtek-scra.jar')
implementation files('libs/univocity-parsers-2.6.3.jar')
implementation 'com.simplify:partner-sdk-android:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
 layout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2'
implementation files('libs/mtscra.jar')
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:2.15.0'
implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:3.0.0'

implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:4.2.3'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.3.4'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```